# PHP codes works in ver. 5.2, not in 5.3

Tags: php

Is there any way to rewrite the following code so that it works in an environment running PHP version 5.2.x? It works just fine running in version 5.3.5 (dev), but my shared hosting environment (prod) runs 5.2 and throws this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/myperf7/ public_html/inc/store-address.php on line 1

Here's the offending code:

```
<?php

function storeAddress(){

    // Validation
    if(!$_GET['email']){ return "No email address provided"; } 

    if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $_GET['email'])) {
        return "Email address is invalid"; 
    }

    require_once('MCAPI.class.php');
    // grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
    $api = new MCAPI('XXXXXXX');

    // grab your List's Unique Id by going to http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/
    // Click the "settings" link for the list - the Unique Id is at the bottom of that page. 
    $list_id = "XXXXXXX";

    if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], '') === true) {
        // It worked!   
        return 'Success! Check your email to confirm sign up.';
    }else{
        // An error ocurred, return error message   
        return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
    }

}

// If being called via ajax, autorun the function
if(isset($_GET['ajax'])){ echo storeAddress(); }

?>
```

And this is how the store-address.php file is being included from my index.php page:

```
<form id="signup" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
    <input type="text" value="" name="email" class="email" id="email" placeholder="email address" required="required" />
    <div class="clear">
        <input type="submit" value="Notify me" name="subscribe" class="button"/>
    </div>
    <span id="response"><?php require_once('inc/store-address.php'); if(isset($_GET['submit'])){ echo storeAddress(); } ?></span>
</form>
```

Thanks so so so so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred because Netbeans saved my PHP files all in a single line, a problem I didn't pick up on until I opened my code in plain old Notepad. Even when opening a Netbeans-saved file in Notepad++, the code appeared indented and line-broken as normal. But in classic Notepad all the code is in a single line, meaning the script broke as soon as it reached the first "//" comment.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: I guess your shared hosting environment is windows server.

Comment: There are line breaks, but they are Unix-style line breaks. Notepad is probably the only editor that does not understand them.

On Windows, your files should be in Windows-style. There probably is a setting for it somewhere in NetBeans.

Comment: Ya, I sorted out the setting in Netbeans so all is well now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may have some non-whitespace character before your `function`.

Your PHP code seems valid for 5.2 and 5.3.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reviewing the code. But there is nothing but whitespace between the final "p" in php and the "f" in function. However, if I remove some of the whitespace and instead make the first line of code `<?php function storeAddress(){`, then I get a new error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end`

Comment: It might have been something that looks like a whitespace and it's not.

`unexpected $end` usually means you left an unclosed bracket, but I'm unable to find any on your code

Comment: What else could cause `unexpected $end` other than unclosed brackets?

Comment: @mark: I think the issue could be with `preg_match`; see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#88587

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see that could be wrong is the `$api->errorMessage`. Try taking out the whole of that if statement:

```
if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], '') === true) {
    // It worked!   
    return 'Success! Check your email to confirm sign up.';
}else{
    // An error ocurred, return error message   
    return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
}
```

And see if you get an error.